# TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'keepdims')

Tags: python, html, keras

I trained a keras model on Colab to predict skin diseases from images and when I try to call the model through VSCode, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "e:\github\Skin_Disease_Assessment\app.py", line 172, in skinExam
    model = load_model('models/final_mobilenet.h5', compile=True)
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 202, in load_model
    compile)
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py", line 181, in load_model_from_hdf5
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\model_config.py", line 59, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\serialization.py", line 163, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 672, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py", line 669, in from_config
    config, custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py", line 1279, in reconstruct_from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py", line 1261, in process_layer
    layer = deserialize_layer(layer_data, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\serialization.py", line 163, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 675, in deserialize_keras_object
    deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(cls_config)
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 740, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\pooling.py", line 1023, in __init__
    super(GlobalPooling2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 522, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 347, in __init__
    generic_utils.validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Dilrose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 1137, in validate_kwargs
    raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'keepdims')
```

**My Python code**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, session, url_for
from sqlite3 import *
from flask import request
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import cv2
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'abc'

@app.route("/skinExam", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def skinExam():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        path='static/data/'+ f.filename
        f.save(path)
        model = load_model('models/final_mobilenet.h5')
        img1 = image.load_img(f, target_size=(224,224))
        img = cv2.resize(img1, (224,224)) / 255.0
        prediction = model.predict(img.reshape(1,224,224,3))
    return render_template('skinExam.html')
```

**My HTML code**

```
<div class="col-md-6" style='margin-left:250px;'>
        <form class="form-group" action="/skinExam" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Upload Image</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                        Browse… <input type="file" id="imgInp" name="file">
                    </span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>    
            </div>
            <input type='submit' id='upload' class='btn btn-lg btn-success' value='Upload'>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I'm able to predict the disease when I give images on Colab but since my project is a web application, I want the users to input the image through html and get the answer as well on the website.
Can anybody help me in resolving this since I'm not able to understand the issue?

Comment: Did you train the model using keras or using tf.keras?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I used tf.keras. I used a pre-trained model called MobileNet by the way.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Could you tell me what to do when we use keras only and when we use tf.keras for training the model?